# Combine 2 models and display in view

Tags: grails

I have 2 model classes. Lawyer and Appointments.

Lawyer Model

```
int id;
String firstName;
String gender;
String school;
```

Appontment Model

```
int id;
String appDate;
String appTime;
Lawyer lawyer;
```

First i want to show a Lawyer list (This is the view). The Lawyer list should show Lawyer details (Name, Age, School **AND ALSO** appointment time and date).

How can i join these 2 models and display both records in one View

VIEW

I think there's a problem in the View. Initially i generated the view using Scafolding. Is that causing the problem ?

```
<%@ page import="Pro.Appointment"%>

<%@ page import="Pro.Lawyer"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="layout" content="main">
<g:set var="entityName"
    value="${message(code: 'appointment.label', default: 'Appointment')}" />

<g:set var="entityName"
    value="${message(code: ' lawyer.label', default: ' Lawyer ')}" />
<title><g:message code="default.show.label" args="[entityName]" /></title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#show-lawyerr" class="skip" tabindex="-1"><g:message
            code="default.link.skip.label" default="Skip to content&hellip;" /></a>
    <div class="nav" role="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="home" href="${createLink(uri: '/')}"><g:message
                        code="default.home.label" /></a></li>
            <li><g:link class="list" action="list">
                    <g:message code="default.list.label" args="[entityName]" />
                </g:link></li>
            <li><g:link class="create" action="create">
                    <g:message code="default.new.label" args="[entityName]" />
                </g:link></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="show-lawyer" class="content scaffold-show" role="main">
        <h1>
            <g:message code="default.show.label" args="[entityName]" />
        </h1>
        <g:if test="${flash.message}">
            <div class="message" role="status">
                ${flash.message}
            </div>
        </g:if>
        <ol class="property-list lawyer">

            <g:if test="${lawyerInstance?.firstName}">
                <li class="fieldcontain"><span id="firstName-label"
                    class="property-label"><g:message
                            code="lawyer.firstName.label" default="First Name" /></span> <span
                    class="property-value" aria-labelledby="firstName-label"><g:fieldValue
                            bean="${lawyerInstance}" field="firstName" /></span></li>
            </g:if>

            <g:if test="${lawyerInstance?.lastName}">
                <li class="fieldcontain"><span id="lastName-label"
                    class="property-label"><g:message
                            code="lawyer.lastName.label" default="Last Name" /></span> <span
                    class="property-value" aria-labelledby="lastName-label"><g:fieldValue
                            bean="${lawyerInstance}" field="lastName" /></span></li>
            </g:if>

            <g:if test="${lawyerInstance?.gender}">
                <li class="fieldcontain"><span id="gender-label"
                    class="property-label"><g:message code="lawyer.gender.label"
                            default="Gender" /></span> <span class="property-value"
                    aria-labelledby="gender-label
<span
                    class="property-value" aria-labelledby="speciality-label"><g:fieldValue
                            bean="${lawyerInstance}" field="speciality" /></span></li>
            </g:if>



ddfdfdfd
        <g:each var="appointments" in="${lawyer}">
        sdsd
            <p>
                firstdsdsdsName:
                ${lawyer.firstName}
            </p>
            <p>
                gender:
                ${lawyer.gender}
            </p>
            <p>appointments:</p>
            <ul>
                <g:each var="app" in="${lawyer.appointments}">
                    <li>
                        ${app.appointmentTime}
                    </li>
                </g:each>
            </ul>
        </g:each>












</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

First I suggest you to go further and to update the Lawyer model in this way:

```
String firstName
String gender
String school

static hasMany = [appointments: Appointment]
```

Appointment Model:

```
Date appDate
Date appTime

static belongsTo = [lawyer: Lawyer]
```

Using the hasMany and the belongsTo properties changes the default Grails cascading behaviour, saves and updates, to saves, updates and deletes (so if you delete a Lawyer every Lawyer's appointment is also deleted).

To show **every Lawyer and every Lawyer appointment** you can do in this way: first in you controller method return something like `[lawyers: Lawyers.list()]`, then add this code in the view related to this method:

```
<g:each var="lawyer" in="${lawyers}">
    <p>firstName: ${lawyer.firstName}</p>
    <p>gender: ${lawyer.gender}</p>
    <p>appointments:</p>
    <ul>
    <g:each var="app" in="${lawyer.appointments}">
         <li>${app.Date}</li>
    </g:each>
    </ul>
</g:each>
```

Keep in mind that Grails use lazy fetching by default, so probably appointments fields aren't populated and an extra query will be required. [See Grails fetching DSL docs](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/GORM.html#fetchingDSL)

Comment: I have edited my code. Please have a look. The problem still remains

Comment: The code that I've provided is for showing a list of Lowyers. But your view a the single Lowyer view.

Comment: I've updated your .gsp code to show appointments of a lawyer, but update your models first, according to mine. Otherwise the lawyer.appointments properties will not works. I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

`Id` is automatically generated field, it's type is `Long`, so you can remove it from both models. Also you can update model:

Lowyer Model:

```
String firstName
String gender
String school

static hasMany = [appointments: Appointment]
```

Appointment Model:

```
Date appDate
Date appTime

static belongsTo = [lowyer: Lowyer]
```

And then you can use something like `lower.appointments`.

**Update**

```
<g:each var="appointments" in="${lawyer}">
    <p>
        firstdsdsdsName:
        ${lawyer.firstName}
    </p>
    <p>
        gender:
        ${lawyer.gender}
    </p>
    <p>appointments:</p>
    <ul>
        <g:each var="app" in="${lawyer.appointments}">
            <li>
                ${app.appointmentTime}
            </li>
        </g:each>
    </ul>
</g:each>
```

Now I think your problem is `<g:each var="app" in="${lawyer.appointments}">` try something like `<g:each var="app" in="${appointments}">`

Comment: I have edited my code. I have included the view code as well. Please have a look. The problem still remains.

Comment: The error i get is `No such property: lastName for class: Pro.Lawyer Possible solutions: lastName, firstName`. I think i have not called the model properly. I have no clue how to solve this. Help

Comment: I created a file called 'index' and copied the same code that was in create.gsp. but it didnt work.I think the view is not rendering the Model.

Comment: @Illep, do you update model like in lifeisfoo's answer or mine? You need to post code of gsp and model and controller, then we will try to help you